# Laravel Left Join with ON condition

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm converting my query into Laravel query builder.

```
" LEFT JOIN grade_level AS f ON (a.customer_type = 1 AND (e.id IS NULL AND d.grade_level_id = f.grade_level_id) OR (e.id IS NOT NULL AND e.grade_level_id = f.grade_level_id) ) "
```

I'm having a problem in AND and OR condition in the middle of my query.

```
->leftJoin("grade_level", function ($join) {
  $join->on("transaction_db.customer_type" , "=", 1);   
  $join->on("enrollment.id", "=", "");
  $join->on("student.grade_level_id", "=","grade_level.grade_level_id");
  $join->orOn("enrollment.id", "=" "", "enrollment.grade_level_id", "=", "grade_level.grade_level_id");
})
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem with that? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanna share we fixed our issue here.

```
$transactions->where(function($query) use ($glid) {
         $query->where(DB::raw("transaction_db.customer_type"), "!=", 1)
               ->orWhere(function($query1) use ($glid) {
                $query1->where(DB::raw("transaction_db.customer_type"), 1)
                       ->where("enrollment.grade_level_id", "=", $glid);
         });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, you can still do the following:

```
->leftJoin("grade_level", function ($join) {
  $join->on(DB::raw("(a.customer_type = 1 AND (e.id IS NULL AND d.grade_level_id = f.grade_level_id) OR (e.id IS NOT NULL AND e.grade_level_id = f.grade_level_id) )");
})
```

Comment: Hmmm... can't solve my problem but the idea is there thankyouuu bro anyways